# $_ value in perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to validate my script whether its correct or not. Bascially i am trying to avoid duplicate entry in @ProtectSuperGroups by using ( grep { $_ ne $1 } @ProtectSuperGroups).

However, I find that $_ is print blank which leads to me to doubt on this.

```
foreach my $group (@ProtectSuperGroups)
{
    chomp($group);
    chomp($group);

    my @ProtectSuperGroupLines = qx($p4 -ztag group -o $group);

    foreach my $line (@ProtectSuperGroupLines)
    {

        if ($line =~ /\.\.\.\s+Users\d{1,3}\s+(.*)$/) 
        {
            push(@ProtectSuperUsers, "$1");

        }

        if ( ($line =~ /\.\.\.\s+Subgroups\d{1,3}\s+(.*)$/) && ( grep { $_ ne $1 } @ProtectSuperGroups)) 
        {
            push(@ProtectSuperGroups, "$1");
        }

    }
}
```

Sample program to print $_ is blank as well..

```
my @array = ( "catchme", "if", "you", "can" );
my $element = "catchme";
if (  grep { $_ eq $element } @array )
{
  print "$)\n"; 
  print "Here's what we found\n";
}
else
{
  print "Sorry, \"$element\" not found in \@array\n";
}
```

Can you please add your experience and suggest me better solution. Basically I want to avoid pushing duplicate entry in my array called @ProtectSuperGroups. My Perl version is v5.8.8

Comment: Your sample program works for me (the `if(grep)` test succeeds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the first shot i don't see your mistake, but if you want to prevent duplicates you can add your entries in a hash and check before each push, if the value exists in the hash

```
my %ProtectSuperGroups;
...
if ( ($line =~ /\.\.\.\s+Subgroups\d{1,3}\s+(.*)$/) && !exists $ProtectSuperGroups{$1} )
{
    push(@ProtectSuperGroups, "$1");
    $ProtectSuperGroups{$1} = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (  grep { $_ eq $element } @array )
```

Inside `grep`, `$_` is local to the block. The `$_` outside is unaffected.

So for your example to work, it should be rewritten:

```
if ( grep { $_ eq $element } @array ) {
  print "$element\n";  # There was a typographical error. You used `$)`
  print "Here's what we found\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Universally, if want to avoid duplicate entry in any array (so want unique elements), you have many solutions. Two of them:

### With List::MoreUtils

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
my @unique = uniq @input_array;
```

The above is straightforward.

### With the helper hash

```
my %helper;
my @unique = grep { ! $helper{$_}++ } @input_array;
```

If the element doesn't exists in the helper hash it is unique, otherwise only count it..